# Ghidra not displaying member function call

Tags: ghidra, pe

[image]

On lines 67, 70 and 77 ghidra makes a call to what I assume is a member function, but it does not show me which member function. Why is that?

Example from line 70:

(**(code **)(*(longlong *)metaStream + 0xd8))(metaStream)

Call in assembly:

qword ptr [RAX + 0xd8]

How can I make ghidra show me which function is being called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Ghidra for whatever reason cannot determine what the actual target of this call is. This might just be a limitation of the C++ support in Ghidra. There are plugins that try to support this better:

- https://github.com/astrelsky/Ghidra-Cpp-Class-Analyzer
- https://insights.sei.cmu.edu/blog/using-ooanalyzer-to-reverse-engineer-object-oriented-code-with-ghidra/

but you can also do this manually if you already know the target function via manual reverse engineering:

```py
ref = program.referenceManager.addMemoryReference(
                    callsite, # FROM, the address of the call instruction
                    func_address, //TO, the address of the function being called
                    RefType.UNCONDITIONAL_CALL,
                    SourceType.USER_DEFINED,
                    0)
program.referenceManager.setPrimary(ref, true)
```